# Updating a products inventory label based on the inventory of each sku for each product

Tags: postgresql

I have the inventory label for each product and its skuid.   A product can have 1 more Skuid.

product_skus_inventories table:

```
ProductID   SkuID   Inventory_Label
123         a1      InStock
123         a2      OutOfStock
123         a3      NULL
```

I want to update the below table that is a summary:

```
product_summary
- product_id
- inventory_label (values can be InSock, OutOfStock or Partial)
```

The logic is as follows:

1. if all SkuID's for a given productID "InStock" or NULL, then "InStock".
2. if any of the SkuIds have "InStock", and other's have different value then "Partial".
3. otherwise, "OutOfStock".

Is it possible to have this type of logic in a update query?

Answer (score 2):

[Collect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) label combinations [per product](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) and specify summary of each combination [`case`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/93IyPtLM)

```sql
select productid,
       case array_agg(distinct inventory_label)
              filter(where inventory_label is not null)
         when '{InStock}'            then 'InStock'
         when '{InStock,OutOfStock}' then 'Partial'
         else 'OutOfStock'
       end as inventory_label
from product_skus_inventories
group by productid;
```

This can be used as an update source, as shown at the end of the demo.

Making this a [`view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) or a [`materialized view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html), using it as a source for an [`insert into...on conflict do update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) or a [`merge`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html)(also in the demo), could potentially make more sense.

Comment: Nice solution.  You can also cheat by using `avg()`.  https://dbfiddle.uk/XFIt77mz  With three or more conditions, you can use `bit_or()`.  P.S. Thank you for the helpful reference links in my other answer.

Comment: To note: `'{InStock,OutOfStock}' <> '{OutOfStock,InStock}'`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Your note seems to assume `'{OutOfStock,InStock}'` is possible. [It's not.](https://dbfiddle.uk/RpHyR9jG)

Comment: @MikeOrganek I gave `bit_or()` [a shot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75804652/5298879).

Comment: Of course `'{OutOfStock,InStock}'` is possible: https://dbfiddle.uk/sxz1BUKJ That's just one of many ways your query can fail. The sort algorithm applied by `DISTINCT` without explicit `ORDER BY` is an implementation detail that can change without notice from one major version to the next. And Postgres is free to chose an alternative hashing algorithm instead of the sort even in current versions. A quick fix is `array_agg(distinct inventory_label ORDER BY inventory_label)`, but I wouldn't use this query at all.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That's like arguing your `bool_and(inventory_label) THEN 'InStock'` can fail because someone can encode `InStock` as `false` (***among other ways*** to mirror both the logic and the tone). This works for `text`, as well as `enum` I suggested in the demo. If you want to hardcode reverse order and lose `text` fallback, it only makes sense to follow it defining the case combination. Config or version changes altering implied defaults need to be fixed by specifying an explicit override - nothing to argue with. Not sure how that's relevant, but I wouldn't use yours either.

Answer (score 2):

[Alternatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) to my [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75770963/5298879), at @[Mike Organek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13808319/mike-organek)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75737355/updating-a-products-inventory-label-based-on-the-inventory-of-each-sku-for-each/75801281#comment133671143_75770963) to try other [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

- `count(distinct inventory_label)` combinations: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/t-ymB2Su)

  ```sql
  select productid,
         case count(distinct inventory_label) --this auto-skips `null`
             when 2 then 'Partial'            --2 means {InStock,OutOfStock}
             when 1 then min(inventory_label) --we want whatever that 1 was
             else        'OutOfStock'--unless null-only labels mean 'InStock'
         end
  from product_skus_inventories 
  group by productid;
  ```
- With [`bit`s](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.5.1.1.1), using encodings: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QimypiP3)

  - 2 (binary `10`) for `InStock`,
  - 1 (binary `01`) for `OutOfStock`,
  - getting a `11`(decimal 3) from `bit_or()` when both are found, or `10`(2) for just `InStock`

  ```sql
  select productid,
         case bit_or((inventory_label='InStock')::int+01)  --F=01, T=10
           when 3 then 'Partial'--3 is binary 11,found 10 as well as 01
           when 2 then 'InStock'--2 is InStock, because bit_or found 10's only
           else        'OutOfStock'--unless null-only labels mean 'InStock'
         end as inventory_label
  from product_skus_inventories
  group by productid;
  ```

I prefer the [`array_agg(distinct inventory_label)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75770963/5298879) for its readability. These are all simple, but that one also self-comments. Still, `count()` is a `filter` shorter, and `bit_or()` is [faster](https://dbfiddle.uk/ROJ-nh5c).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view of your table that generates the status which can then be easily queried when you need the values. If instead you need to run an UPDATE to materialize the inventory label, then you can use the SELECT inside `JOIN LATERAL` to get the status to insert for a given product_id.

The logic for the status is as follows:

1. Check if the number of rows for a given product_id matches the number of rows after filtering out `out_of_stock`.
2. Since we know that at least 1 `out_of_stock` exists for this product_id as the previous clause didn't match, we just need to check if there exists at least 1 `in_stock` or `NULL`.
3. Else, `out_of_stock`.

```sql
CREATE VIEW product_summary as (
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id, _status.inventory_label 
    FROM product_skus_inventories psi_outer
    JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) = (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE psi_inner.inventory_label IS NULL OR psi_inner.inventory_label='in_stock'))) THEN 'in_stock' 
                    WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_skus_inventories _psi WHERE psi_outer.product_id = _psi.product_id AND (_psi.inventory_label IS NULL OR _psi.inventory_label='in_stock'))) THEN 'partial'
                    ELSE 'out_of_stock'
                    END AS inventory_label
        FROM product_skus_inventories psi_inner
        WHERE psi_inner.product_id = psi_outer.product_id
    ) AS _status ON true
);
```

Comment: You can [speed it up](https://dbfiddle.uk/nyeFKU2Q) and correct the `in_stock` status for products labeled with only `null` by sticking to `exists` in both cases. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/K6odQKS-)

Answer (score 1):

### Basic query

#### With original table definition

Don't count or aggregate all rows. You are looking for a boolean result, basically. And these two aggregate functions happen to fit your task description *exactly*:

- [`bool_and()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) covers case *"1."*
- [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) covers case *"2."*

Makes for a fast and simple query:

```sql
SELECT productid
     , CASE WHEN bool_and(inventory_label = 'InStock') THEN 'InStock'
            WHEN bool_or (inventory_label = 'InStock') THEN 'Partial'
            ELSE                                            'OutOfStock' END AS label
FROM   product_skus_inventories
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0tPtoHhf)

#### Better with [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html)

`product_skus_inventories.inventory_label` can be "in", "out", or `null`. That's a **`boolean`** quantity. Use the fitting, superior data type. Only occupies 1 byte and makes everything shorter, simpler and faster.

To convert the table (triggers a complete table rewrite with exclusive lock):

```sql
ALTER TABLE product_skus_inventories
ALTER COLUMN inventory_label TYPE boolean USING inventory_label = 'InStock'; -- that's all!
```

Then run `VACUUM ANALYZE product_skus_inventories` once.

Now, the query is even simpler and faster:

```sql
SELECT productid
     , CASE WHEN bool_and(inventory_label) THEN 'InStock'
            WHEN bool_or(inventory_label)  THEN 'Partial'
            ELSE                                'OutOfStock' END AS label
FROM   product_skus_inventories
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M90uA81y)

### "Update" summary table

The appropriate action is an [UPSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT), really. [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) in Postgres.

Assuming this table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product_summary (
  product_id      int PRIMARY KEY  -- needs PK or UNIQUE contraint / index
, inventory_label text             -- still text?
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO product_summary AS p (product_id, inventory_label)
SELECT productid
     , CASE WHEN bool_and(inventory_label) THEN 'InStock'
            WHEN bool_or(inventory_label)  THEN 'Partial'
            ELSE                                'OutOfStock' END AS label
FROM   product_skus_inventories
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1  -- optional
ON     CONFLICT (product_id) DO UPDATE
SET    inventory_label = EXCLUDED.inventory_label
WHERE  p.inventory_label IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.inventory_label;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6yyl3CzS)

Note the added `WHERE` clause. This skips all updates that wouldn't change the state, typically making the query *a lot* cheaper. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Answer (score 0):

How about using this kind of approach.

```
UPDATE product_summary
SET inventory_label =
  CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM product_skus_inventories
      WHERE ProductID = product_summary.product_id
      AND Inventory_Label IN ('InStock', NULL)
    ) AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM product_skus_inventories
      WHERE ProductID = product_summary.product_id
      AND Inventory_Label NOT IN ('InStock', NULL)
    ) THEN 'InStock'
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM product_skus_inventories
      WHERE ProductID = product_summary.product_id
      AND Inventory_Label = 'InStock'
    ) THEN 'Partial'
    ELSE 'OutOfStock'
  END;
```

This query first checks if all SkuIDs for a given productID are either "InStock" or NULL, and updates the inventory_label to "InStock" if that's the case.

If not, it checks if any SkuIDs have "InStock" and updates the inventory_label to "Partial" if that's the case.

If neither condition is met, it updates the inventory_label to "OutOfStock".

Comment: I'd upvote, but that's 3 `exists` instead of 2 [suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75737355/updating-a-products-inventory-label-based-on-the-inventory-of-each-sku-for-each/75835627#comment133729765_75770245). Also, it suffers from the same problem where it's saying `null` are `'InStock'`. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Pqn2Qaa)

Comment: Come to think of it, I assumed this *'if all SkuID's for a given productID "InStock" or NULL, then "InStock"'* would reasonably mean: `'{InStock,null}'` and `'{InStock}'` combinations lead to `'InStock'` status, while `'{null}'` should fall into the *"otherwise"* category of `'{null}'`, `'{OutOfStock,null}'`, `'{OutOfStock}'`. That could be an overinterpretation or even plain misinterpretation on my part (and Erwin's, as it looks like he did the same).

Comment: You've got the point. Thank you for letting me know. I updated the answer. Any idea how to improve it?

Comment: If you want to join the "`null` means `'OutOfStock'`" movement (even though the contrary turns out to be a perfectly reasonable assumption), you can fix it in a similar way to oaowren's: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/i0YPvQdu).